# Why I can't create directory with php mkdir()?

Tags: php, mkdir

When I create new directory with `mkdir($path, 0755);` I have error:

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /home/u235555603/public_html/vacancies/index.php on line 51

In directory "vacancies" I have 755 rights.

What I should do?

Thank's for help.

Comment: "In directory "vacancies" I have 755 rights. " - Does the account that Apache is running under have that same permission?

Comment: The warning itself shows the folder doesn't have enough permissions... Give the permissions for the folder and then do it..

Comment: Change permissions using this... chmod 777 <filename>

Comment: @phpfresher When I try change to 777 in FileZilla, It revert them to 755.

Comment: @phpfresher - granting global permissions to a folder isn't a solution to every problem, it's a security hole

Comment: ohh... @MarkBaker.. am not using Linux, so i dunno much about it... i just know few of them... so i suggested it... and thank you for telling me a point about security... :)

Comment: @MarkBaker What  can you suggest?

Comment: @AlexanderSeredenko the folder needs to be writeable by your Web server user, which might be `www-data`, for example. Look at `$_ENV['USER']` to find out.

Comment: I'd suggest ensuring that the web server group is the group for the folder permissions, rather than the login user's group, or use a full acl system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, make sure your directory is writable by the user your webserver runs under. For apache under *nix, you can do:

```
ps aux | egrep 'apache|http|nginx'
```

And look for the username(s) in the first column.

As for creating a directory in PHP safely, check the result of `is_writable($parentDir)` before attempting to create the directory. See [is_writable](https://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).